# Salesforce Fax Integration

Tags: integration

Please let me know how to integrate Salesforce and Fax? Both inbound and outbound fax integrations.

Comment: You can use [interfax](https://www.interfax.net/en)  API to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Twilio to send Faxes](https://www.twilio.com/fax):

This code uses the Twilio for Salesforce REST API query builder:

```
    TwilioFaxRequest request; // create your request

    TwilioSF.TwilioApiClient api = new TwilioSF.TwilioApiClient();
    api.setBaseUrl('https://fax.twilio.com/');
    api.setApiVersion('v1');
    api.addUrlPart('Faxes');

    api.addParam('To', request.To);
    api.addParam('From',request.From_x);
    api.addParam('MediaUrl', request.MediaUrl); // url to a PDF
    api.addParam('Quality', request.Quality);
    api.addParam('StoreMedia', request.StoreMedia);

    TwilioSF.TwilioApiClientResponse response = api.doPost();

    System.debug(response);
    System.debug(response.hasError());
    System.debug(response.getErrorMessage());

    String sid = response.getTwilioJsonParser().get('sid').getString();
```

If you *don't want to use* the Twilio for Salesforce package:

```
public with sharing class TwilioFaxApi {

    private HttpClient client;

    public TwilioFaxApi() {
        client = new HttpClient('https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes');
    }

    public TwilioFaxResponse post(TwilioFaxRequest request) {

        String body = '';
        body += 'From=' + urlEncode(request.From_x);
        body += '&To=' + urlEncode(request.To);
        body += '&StoreMedia=' + request.StoreMedia;
        body += '&Quality=' + request.Quality;
        body += '&Ttl=' + request.Ttl;
        body += '&MediaUrl=' + urlEncode(request.MediaUrl);

        Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
        headers.put('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Authorization);

        HttpResponse response = client.post(headers, body);

        String responseBody = response.getBody();

        responseBody = responseBody.replace('from', 'from_x');

        return (TwilioFaxResponse) JSON.deserialize(responseBody, TwilioFaxResponse.class);
    }

    private String urlEncode(String value) {
        return EncodingUtil.urlEncode(value,'UTF-8');
    }

    private String Authorization {
        get {
            String[] args = new List<String> { AccountSID, AuthToken };
            String value = String.format('{0}:{1}', args);
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(value));
        }
    }

    private String AccountSID {
        get {
            return 'Account_SID';
        }
    }

    private String AuthToken {
        get {
            return 'Auth_Token';
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpClient**

```
public with sharing class HttpClient {

    private String endpoint;

    public HttpClient(String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public HttpResponse post(Map<String, String> headers, String body) {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setTimeout(120000); // 2 Minutes
        request.setCompressed(false); 
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); 
        for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
            request.setHeader(header, headers.get(header)); 
        } 
        request.setBody(body);      

        HttpResponse httpResponse = new Http().send(request);

        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

**Fax Request**

```
public class TwilioFaxRequest {

    public String To { get; set; }
    public String From_x { get; set; }
    public String MediaUrl { get; set; }
    public String StatusCallback { get; set; }
    public String Quality { get; set; }
    public String StoreMedia { get; set; }
    public String Ttl { get; set; } 

    public TwilioFaxRequest() {
        this.Quality = 'fine';
        this.StoreMedia = 'true';
        this.Ttl = '120'; // 2 hours
    }
}
```

**Fax Response**

```
public class TwilioFaxResponse {

    public String Account_Sid { get; set; }
    public String Api_Version { get; set; }
    public Datetime Date_Created { get; set; }
    public Datetime Date_Updated { get; set; }
    public Datetime Date_Sent { get; set; }
    public String Sid { get; set; }
    public String Direction { get; set; }
    public String Price { get; set; }
    public String Price_Unit { get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
    public String Error_Code { get; set; }
    public String Error_Message { get; set; }
    public String To { get; set; }
    public String From_x { get; set; }
    public String Media_Url { get; set; }
    public String Media_Sid { get; set; }
    public String Num_Pages { get; set; }
    public String Quality { get; set; }
    public String Duration { get; set; }
    public TwilioFaxLink Links { get; set; }
    public String Url { get; set; }
}

public with sharing class TwilioFaxLink { 
    public String Media { get; set; }
}
```

**Twilio for Salesforce packages**

- To install the package in your [production instance](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1N0000029Jrh)
- To install the package in your [test instance](https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1N0000029Jrh)

References:

- [Use Twilio REST APIs from Apex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/salesforce/using-twilio-rest-apis-apex)
- [Twilio Fax Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/quickstart)

Comment: I didn't know Twilio did fax as well - thank you!

Comment: I noticed you're using the new Twilio for Salesforce package.  Is it possible to leverage their helper classes/API without buying any licenses/seats?  I've always just worked off the [old v4.2.0 package](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1a000000AQzf) and never upgraded to the new one, since it may cost money

Comment: @BrianMiller I am not paying anything. I believe those package links are for earlier versions of the package before it required a license

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the quick reply! I'll try it out in the sandbox

Comment: @BrianMiller I've added my code to create faxes without the Twilio package

Comment: You've gone beyond the call of duty - this is very helpful

Comment: You forgot to set the authentication headers in the HttpClient::post() method.  I did an edit to adjust this

Comment: Did you create the `TwilioFaxLink` class by hand (if so, can you update the post with this?), or was this part of the Twilio package?

Comment: @BrianMiller updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use InterFax, RightFax and other fax service providers.

InterFax is well known and easy to integrate with Salesforce using 2 ways:
1) SOAP API 
2) Rest API

### For REST API, please refer below link:

- https://rest.interfax.net/outbound/help
- https://rest.interfax.net/inbound/help